# How to send file to apps script using plain POST request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, google-apps-script, request

im doing simple file uploader to apps script but I faced some troubles with uploading data as file. Lets say I have this code:

```
function doPost(e) {
  console.log(e)
}
```

and I do a simple POST request in node.js

```
  let formData = {
    theFile: {
      value: fs.createReadStream('myawersome.file'),
      options: {
        filename: 'myawersome.file',
        contentType: 'some/mimetype'
      }
    }
  }
  let params = {
    url: 'my-script-url',
    followAllRedirects: true,
    formData: formData
  }
  request.post(params)
```

So, whats the problem. I dont see any files in my `e` param in `doPost`. That is my console.log output

```
{"queryString":"","parameter":{},"contextPath":"","parameters":{},"contentLength":9483}
```

I can see that I have some data in request, but everything is empty. `e.parameters.theFile` and `e.theFile` are `undefined`. Where is my file?

Answer (score 1):

the call of `createReadStream` just create the stream but don't read the file

to read the file, try that :

```
var rs = fs.createReadStream('myawersome.file');


rs.on("data", function (chunk) {

    var content = chunk.toString();


    var formData = {
        theFile: {
            value: content,
            options: {
                filename: 'myawersome.file',
                contentType: 'some/mimetype'
            }
        }
    }

    var params = {
        url: 'my-script-url',
        followAllRedirects: true,
        formData: formData
    }

    request.post(params)

});
rs.resume(); // this launches the read
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I didnt try this but decidet to send file as base64 string in post body and it works well with apps script